# What's the number in XCode's console in square brackets?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsapplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone nslog output format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968679/iphone-nslog-output-format)

> 2012-07-25 16:25:08:491 MyProject[**2488:403**] App finished
>   launching.

This might be an easy question, but what are those numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968679/iphone-nslog-output-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the process id followed by the thread id.
Explained [here](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-561.html).

Comment: this answer no longer applies to Xcode 8.x

Comment: this [link](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSLog.m) has helped me track down the proper functions to call to replicate the output from `NSLog()`

Comment: and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8995737/947342) is how you get the iOS 8+ version of the thread id