# Getting "throwing -10878" when adding a source to a mixer

Tags: ios, macos, audiokit, avaudioengine

AudioKit, macOS:

When I do mixer.addInput(myAudioPlayer), the program outputs this message:

2021-09-16 11:41:44.578038+0200 ShowTime[16140:1611137] throwing -10878

... numerous times.

Do you know what -10878 is, and how to fix it?

I would also be interested in knowing what "ShowTime[16140:1611137]" means. Can I use these numbers to track where my program fails?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding "ShowTime[16140:1611137]": Guessing that your app's name is ShowTime? If so, 16140 is the process ID and 1611137 is thread ID (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995737/176304).

Answer (score 6):

This happens independently of AudioKit.

It has to do with AVAudioEngine or some lower-level component that AVAudioEngine uses.

I can verify that it happens specifically when I connect a AVAudioPlayerNode to the engine's mainmixer.  If I connect the player to the outputNode directly instead, then it doesn't happen... but I also suspect that it's harmless -- it also happens in known production code and Apple code samples.

I only see this "bug" when using an emulator running IOS 15.2.  It doesn't occur on my real device (IOS 14.4), OR on an emulator running 14.4.

This means that it is a bug or simply "log noise" introduced some time between IOS 14.4 and 15.2.  I haven't tested any versions in-between.

PS - I don't see the "Showtime[####:####]" part of the log, so that part probably is coming from AudioKit -- wrapping the log with NSLog.